# Adding floats with gmp gives "correct" results, sort of 

Tags: visual-c++, floating-point, bignum, gmp

In the code below I use `mpf_add` to add the string representation of two floating values. What I don't understand at this point is why `2.2 + 3.2 = 5.39999999999999999999999999999999999999`. I would have thought that `gmp` was smart enough to give `5.4`.

What am I not comprehending about how gmp does floats?

(BTW, when I first wrote this I wasn't sure how to insert a decimal point, thus the plus/minus digit stuff at the end)

```
BSTR __stdcall FBIGSUM(BSTR p1, BSTR p2 ) {
  USES_CONVERSION;

  F(n1);
  F(n2);
  F(res);

  LPSTR sNum1 = W2A( p1 );
  LPSTR sNum2 = W2A( p2 );

  mpf_set_str( n1, sNum1, 10 );
  mpf_set_str( n2, sNum2, 10 );

  mpf_add( res, n1, n2 );

  char * buff =  (char *) _alloca( 1024 );
  char expBuffer[ 20 ];
  mp_exp_t exp;

  mpf_get_str(buff, &exp, 10, 0, res);

  char * temp = ltoa( (long) exp, expBuffer, 10 );
  if (exp >= 0) {
    strcat(buff, "+" );
  }
  strcat(buff, expBuffer );

  BSTR bResult = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR( buff );
  return bResult;
}
```

Comment: Easiest is to use mpq_t, operations on rationals are exact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the inherent error of using floating-point arithmetic in a binary environment.

See the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard for more information.

Answer (score 1):

What [warren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4418/warren) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178952/adding-floats-with-gmp-gives-correct-results-sort-of#178978).

You might have better results if you use binary coded decimal instead of floating point numbers, although I can't really direct you to any libraries for that.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually ended up answering this myself. The solution for me was to do in code what I used to do in school. The method works like this:

1. Take each number and make sure that the number of digits to the right of the decimal point are the same. So if adding `2.1` and `3.457`, 'normalise' the first one to `2.100`. Keep a record of the number of digits that are to the right of the decimal, in this case, three.
2. Now remove the decimal point and use `mpz_add` to add the two numbers, which have now become `2100` and `3457`. The result is `5557`.
3. Finally, reinsert the decimal point three characters (in this case) from the right, giving the correct answer of `5.557`.

I prototyped the solution in VBScript (below)

```
function fadd( n1, n2 )
    dim s1, s2, max, mul, res
    normalise3 n1, n2, s1, s2, max
    s1 = replace( s1, ".", "" )
    s2 = replace( s2, ".", "" )
    mul = clng(s1) + clng(s2)
    res = left( mul, len(mul) - max ) & "." & mid( mul, len( mul ) - max + 1 )
    fadd = res
end function

sub normalise3( byval n1, byval n2, byref s1, byref s2, byref numOfDigits )
    dim a1, a2
    dim max
    if instr( n1, "." ) = 0 then n1 = n1 & "."
    if instr( n2, "." ) = 0 then n2 = n2 & "."
    a1 = split( n1, "." )
    a2 = split( n2, "." )
    max = len( a1(1) )
    if len( a2(1) ) > max then max = len( a2( 1 ) )
    s1 = a1(0) & "." & a1(1) & string( max - len( a1( 1 )), "0" )
    s2 = a2(0) & "." & a2(1) & string( max - len( a2( 1 )), "0" )
    numOfDigits = max
end sub
```

and finally in Visual C++ (below).

```
#define Z(x) mpz_t x; mpz_init( x );

BSTR __stdcall FADD( BSTR p1, BSTR p2 ) {
  USES_CONVERSION;

  LPSTR sP1 = W2A( p1 );
  LPSTR sP2 = W2A( p2 );

  char LeftOf1[ 1024 ];
  char RightOf1[ 1024 ];
  char LeftOf2[ 1024 ];
  char RightOf2[ 1024 ];
  char * dotPos;
  long numOfDigits;
  int i;
  int amtOfZeroes;

  dotPos = strstr( sP1, "." );
  if ( dotPos == NULL ) {
    strcpy( LeftOf1, sP1 );
    *RightOf1 = '\0';
  } else {
    *dotPos = '\0';
    strcpy( LeftOf1, sP1 );
    strcpy( RightOf1, (dotPos + 1) );
  }

  dotPos = strstr( sP2, "." );
  if ( dotPos == NULL ) {
    strcpy( LeftOf2, sP2 );
    *RightOf2 = '\0';
  } else {
    *dotPos = '\0';
    strcpy( LeftOf2, sP2 );
    strcpy( RightOf2, (dotPos + 1) );
  }

  numOfDigits = strlen( RightOf1 ) > strlen( RightOf2 ) ? strlen( RightOf1 ) : strlen( RightOf2 );

  strcpy( sP1, LeftOf1 );
  strcat( sP1, RightOf1 );
  amtOfZeroes = numOfDigits - strlen( RightOf1 );
  for ( i = 0; i < amtOfZeroes; i++ ) {
    strcat( sP1, "0" );
  }
  strcpy( sP2, LeftOf2 );
  strcat( sP2, RightOf2 );
  amtOfZeroes = numOfDigits - strlen( RightOf2 );
  for ( i = 0; i < amtOfZeroes; i++ ) {
    strcat( sP2, "0" );
  }


  Z(n1);
  Z(n2);
  Z(res);

  mpz_set_str( n1, sP1, 10 );
  mpz_set_str( n2, sP2, 10 );
  mpz_add( res, n1, n2 );

  char * buff =  (char *) _alloca( mpz_sizeinbase( res, 10 ) + 2 + 1 );

  mpz_get_str(buff, 10, res);

  char * here = buff + strlen(buff) - numOfDigits; 

  memmove( here + 1, here, strlen(buff)); // plus trailing null
  *(here) = '.';

  BSTR bResult = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR( buff );
  return bResult;
}
```

I accept that the C is a bit ... well ... dodgy, so please feel free to critique it. All helpful comments gratefully received.

I went on from here to implement FSUB and FMUL as well. FDIV was not nearly so satisfying, ending up in three versions and using rational numbers.