# Why adding these two double does not give correct answer?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retain precision with Doubles in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java)

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class q2{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        double x=4.02, y=0.05;  
        out.println(x+y);  
    }  
}
```

Output:

> 4.069999999999999

Why is it outputting the that. I thought it would be 4.07. Please explain why this happens in java ?

**Sorry for the inaccurate Question title. I can't have a better title than this**

Comment: Why? It's the correct answer, considering the real values of x and y.

Comment: The question is, in any future calculation will 4.07 be any different to 4.06999999999999.  If you want your final answer to some specific precision then just round at the end.

Comment: The discovery of floating point arithmetic marks an important milestone in every programmer's life. Congratulations. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because some numbers -- such as 0.1 -- cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point.

Consider reading the following article:

- **[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point
  Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)**

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing a rounding error.  See [How to resolve a Java Rounding Double issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue)

To resolve it you can change to BigDecimal instead of double as mentioned in the accepted answer to the linked question.