# How to compare two double values in Java?

Tags: java

A simple comparison of two double values in Java creates some problems. Let's consider the following simple code snippet in Java.

```
package doublecomparision;

final public class DoubleComparision 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double a = 1.000001;
        double b = 0.000001;

        System.out.println("\n"+((a-b)==1.0));
    }
}
```

---

The above code appears to return `true`, the evaluation of the expression `((a-b)==1.0)` but it doesn't. It returns `false` instead because the evaluation of this expression is `0.9999999999999999` which was actually expected to be `1.0` which is not equal to `1.0` hence, the condition evaluates to boolean `false`. What is the best and suggested way to overcome such a situation?

Comment: This is because doubles and floats cannot express every numerical value. They are really using approximations to represent the value.

Comment: The title of question is very misleading. The Author of question is actually asking, how to do precise math operations on double typ. Answer is you cant. If you have to, use BigDecimalr or similar. Those have .... at least theoretically, unlimited precision.

Comment: Here is good article: https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparing-doubles

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Basically you shouldn't do exact comparisons, you should do something like this:

```
double a = 1.000001;
double b = 0.000001;
double c = a-b;
if (Math.abs(c-1.0) <= 0.000001) {...}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Double's compare method. Check this link : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_compare.htm

Comment: But if you use Double.compare, note that 

(1) If d1 and d2 both represent Double.NaN, then the method returns true, even though Double.NaN==Double.NaN has the value false; and


(2) If d1 represents +0.0 while d2 represents -0.0, or vice versa, the method returns the value false, even though +0.0==-0.0 has the value true.

This definition allows hash tables to operate properly.

Comment: this could also use `Math.ulp()` instead of a fixed error like `0.000001` (despite ot that obvious)

Comment: Wait guys, okay, we can compare to doubles on the condition of equality considering desired accuracy, but how to compare which double variable is __bigger__? I don't totally get it.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using doubles for decimal arithemetic, please use  java.math.BigDecimal. It would produce the expected results.

For reference take a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue)

Comment: BigDecimal is sometimes not a viable solution.

Comment: But the poster was specifically asking about comparing doubles

Comment: @mcfinnigan Could you please give an example when BigDecimal is not a viable solution? Because I am wondering what's the point of using double in production systems if it cannot perform such an easy operation as mentioned by original poster...

Comment: @bridgemns Well, performance, memory footprint, multiplatform comes into mind. However fast BigDecimal is, it is still much slower than double which has it's own hardware implementation in the CPU. It uses more memory. And if you program multiplatform (in Kotlin for example), BigDecimal is not represented on all platforms (Javascript, Native). I agree that for money related calculations you should use BigDecimal. Other cases, it's not so simple.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Double.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-); It compares the two specified double values.

Comment: I don't believe Double.compare in itself solves the problem that the poster was asking. You'd still need the abs and threshold

Comment: the *advantage* of `compare` is that it accounts for `NaN` and `-0.0` - questions problem is sure not solved by that

Comment: I belive it does, jsut walk through: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Double.java#l1016 and  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Double.java#l815

Answer (score 3):

```
        int mid = 10;
        for (double j = 2 * mid; j >= 0; j = j - 0.1) {
            if (j == mid) {
                System.out.println("Never happens"); // is NOT printed
            }

            if (Double.compare(j, mid) == 0) {
                System.out.println("No way!"); // is NOT printed
            }

            if (Math.abs(j - mid) < 1e-6) {
                System.out.println("Ha!"); // printed
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Gotcha!");
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this line of code:

```
Math.abs(firstDouble - secondDouble) < Double.MIN_NORMAL
```

It returns whether firstDouble is equal to secondDouble. I'm unsure as to whether or not this would work in your exact case (as Kevin pointed out, performing any math on floating points can lead to imprecise results) however I was having difficulties with comparing two double which were, indeed, equal, and yet using the 'compareTo' method didn't return 0.

I'm just leaving this there in case anyone needs to compare to check if they are indeed equal, and not just similar.

Comment: There are already multiple posts about this. Search better in SO.

Comment: and this is also returning `false` for questions data. Error with given data is about `1e-16`, `MIN_NORMAL` is about `2e-308` - way off  {{ maybe you meant to use `Math.ulp()` }}

Answer (score 0):

This should be built into Java. There are a couple libraries that do a good job of safely comparing doubles, with a third 'epsilon' value:

- Guava's DoubleMath:

```
// this returns true if roughlyOne is very close to 1
DoubleMath.fuzzyEquals(1.0, roughlyOne, 0.0001d)
```

- Apache Common's has a very similar method, Precision.equals

And for what its worth, JUnit recently deprecated the equality assert methods that involve doubles that don't also include an epsilon threshold.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use Double.compare(), you may consider use the following:

```
double n1 = 0.1234567890123450;
double n2 = 0.1234567890123449;
boolean res = (Math.abs(n1 - n2) <= 1e-16 * Math.max(Math.abs(n1), 
Math.abs(n2)));
System.out.println(res);
```

however, if you just compare |n1 - n2|, you may get True for the following comparison result:

```
boolean res = (Math.abs(n1 - n2) <= 1e-16);
System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score -4):

Just use Double.compare() method to compare double values.
**Double.compare((d1,d2) == 0)**

```
double d1 = 0.0;
double d2 = 0.0;

System.out.println(Double.compare((d1,d2) == 0))  // true
```

Comment: you'd still need the abs and threshold. Double.compare doesn't do anything magic; if you look at the javadoc it returns "the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2; a value less than 0 if d1 is numerically less than d2; and a value greater than 0 if d1 is numerically greater than d2.", effectively doing d1 == d2 in this case

Answer (score -4):

```
double a = 1.000001;
double b = 0.000001;

System.out.println( a.compareTo(b) );
```

**Returns**:

- -1 : 'a' is numerically less than 'b'.
- 0 : 'a' is equal to 'b'.
- 1 : 'a' is greater than 'b'.

Comment: You can't call methods on primitive types which double is

Comment: and even if you could (or using `Double.valueOf()`, it surely will return that the numbers are different

Comment: and I don't just mean comparing `a` with `b`, but `a-b` with `1.0`

Comment: This has seen my work. Thank you :)

Comment: did the trick for me. thank you !