# How to compute the double values in java with proper output?

Tags: java, android, double, bigdecimal, mathematical-notation

I am writing mathematical function using Java and when I try to compare my result with ms office excel formula function the  accuracy of the both the values missing which make `my comparison(==)` fails in case of double values.

My result:
2.3450414545545569**404E16**

MS excel result:
 
2.3450414545545569**4E16**

I did  some research on it and found few [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java) but it doesn't solve my issue and I can't use the Big decimal as it won't be consistent to my end result.

I couldn't understand why my function shows extra values **(404E16)**  and how it can be formatted to produce output like **(2.34504145455455694E16)**

Answer (score 2):

use `strictfp` in your method. That may solve accuracy problems.

This [link](http://guruzon.com/1/java-basics/access-modifiers/use-of-strictfp-keyword-method-class-examples-tutorial) provides more information on `strictfp`.

Comment: Is that for in Excel ?

Answer (score 1):

If BigDecimal is not an option, this is a good way to compare double values:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081911/3115739

Comment: :But is there a way to convert the my result exactly to ms result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare while ignoring the last digits:

```
boolean equals = Math.abs(myResult - msExcelResult) < 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Codev I tried it and it worked but another problem is I need to maintain consistency between my result and excel result(i.e both should be excatly same).So is there a way to format the my result(2.3450414545545569404E16) like ms result(2.34504145455455694E16) or should I need to follow any standards for double values?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is just a formatting one you just need to use an appropriate format string to output the number. Quite what to use depends on exactly how you are outputting the number but things like `DecimalFormat`, format strings (`System.out.format`), etc will all help you.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html