# Java comparing double values - bigger number

Tags: java, numbers, compare, double

I have two double values, and I want to find which double is bigger as either one could be bigger number.

For example

```
Double a = Value1;
Double b = Value2;
```

Either could be bigger. I need to find out which one is bigger to find the difference between them.

Comment: Wait, what ? Are you looking for the `-` operator ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java

Comment: Or `Math.abs( val1 - val2 )`.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (a > b) { ... }`, etc.?

Comment: yeah a possiblity could be looking for the - operator didn't think about that. how would that be done if so? @Deadly Jesus

Comment: @TedHopp. That is probably the simplest, actually! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare doubles with the `<` or `>` operator.

But you want to get the difference. That can be done simply by taking the absolute value of the subtraction of either one from the other.

```
Double difference = Math.abs( val1 - val2 );
```

Comment: don't know why i didn't think this had a code blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo(java.lang.Double)), Double is implementing Comparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but I would recommend using Double.compare(val1,val2);, as this is the express purpose for which this method was designed.

This method returns an integer.  If the integer is 0 then the two doubles are equal.  If the integer is less than 0, then val1 is less than val2, and if if the integer is greater than 0, val1 is greater than val2.