# JavaFX progress indicator adding mysterious extra values?

Tags: java, javafx

I am testing out the functionality of progress bars/indicators in javaFX, and when I add a specific value to the indicator it displays a weird and unexpected behavior.

```
public class RunningController {

    public ProgressIndicator progressCircle;

    //This Adds value to the progress indicator
    private double addProgess(){
        double newProgress, currentProgress;
        currentProgress = progressCircle.getProgress();
        System.out.println("Current Process "+ currentProgress);
        newProgress = currentProgress + 0.1;
        System.out.println("New Progress " + newProgress);
        return newProgress;
    }

    //This is tied to a single button press to update the indicator
    public void progressCircleMethod(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        checkProgress();
    }

    //This checks the value of the progress indicator and adds if required
    private void checkProgress() {
        if (progressCircle.getProgress() < 1){
            progressCircle.setProgress(addProgess());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Complete");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run through this, I get some interesting values outputted to the console:

```
//Button Clicked (1)
Current Process 0.0
New Progress 0.1
//Button Clicked (2)
Current Process 0.1
New Progress 0.2
//Button Clicked (3)
Current Process 0.2
New Progress 0.30000000000000004
//Button Clicked (4)
Current Process 0.30000000000000004
New Progress 0.4
//Button Clicked (5)
Current Process 0.4
New Progress 0.5
//Button Clicked (6)
Current Process 0.5
New Progress 0.6
//Button Clicked (7)
Current Process 0.6
New Progress 0.7
//Button Clicked (8)
Current Process 0.7
New Progress 0.7999999999999999
//Button Clicked (9)
Current Process 0.7999999999999999
New Progress 0.8999999999999999
//Button Clicked (10)
Current Process 0.8999999999999999
New Progress 0.9999999999999999
//Button Clicked (11)
Current Process 0.9999999999999999
New Progress 1.0999999999999999
```

Obviously, I would like it to get to 100% in 10 presses and not 11. 
Why are these extra decimal values being added on button press (3) and (8)?

**EDIT:** Totally forgot about the rounding issue in regards to doubles. I could use the accepted answer or use `BigDecimal`. Using `BigDecimal`:

```
private double addProgess(){
    double currentProgress = progressCircle.getProgress();
    BigDecimal currentProgressValue;
    BigDecimal newProgressValue;

    currentProgressValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(currentProgress);
    System.out.println("Current Progress " + currentProgressValue);
    newProgressValue = currentProgressValue.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1d));
    System.out.println("New Progress " + newProgressValue);
    return newProgressValue.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two double values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually reaching effectively 100% in 10 button presses, it's just the inaccuracy of the floating point number that is causing it to be `.9999999` instead of `1`.

For more information on why floating point numbers cause loss of precision ("rounding errors") like this, please see [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate).

An easy way to fix this is instead of using a `double` to track the progress percentage between 0 and 1, use an `int` to track the progress between 0 and 100. Integers don't suffer from the precision issues that floating point types like `double`s do. If you need to use the progress number in a function outside of this that expects a value between 0 and 1, you can always cast your `int` to a `double` and divide it by 100 at that point.