# Error : operator (!=) cannot be applied to double,"null" . How to fix?

Tags: android, xml, database, firebase

```
 if(addressList.get(0).getLatitude() != null){

    fullAddress += addressList.get(0).getLatitude() + " ";

  }
```

Comment: Post your log cat output and Object structure of Address Item to get which data type is used for Latitude or any wrapper class.

Comment: Did you try `if(addressList.get(0).getLatitude() != 0){` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only compare Object types with `null`

Since double is a primitive and not an Object you cannot compare it with `null`. Compare it with number:

```
if(addressList.get(0).getLatitude() != 0){

}
```

Where `0` is the default value of Latitude.

Check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java) for comparing doubles properly.