# operator != cannot be applied to double, null

Tags: android, null, double, latitude-longitude, uber-api

I am getting an error on this code below:

```
  HashMap map = new HashMap();
  map.put("driver", userId);
  map.put("customer", customerId);
  map.put("rating", 0);
  map.put("timestamp", getCurrentTimestamp());
  map.put("destination", destination);
  map.put("location/from/lat", pickupLatLng.latitude);
  map.put("location/from/lng", pickupLatLng.longitude);
  map.put("location/to/lat", destinationLatLng.latitude);
  map.put("location/to/lng", destinationLatLng.longitude);
  map.put("distance", rideDistance);
  historyRef.child(requestId).updateChildren(map);
```

They said to add:

do **if( pickupLatLng.latitude != null &&  pickupLatLng.longitude != null && destinationLatLng.latitude != null && destinationLatLng.longitude != null)** before creating the hashMap, or for each latitude and longitude.

But when i try this i am getting the following error: operator != cannot be applied to double, null

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: A `double` is a primitive type, so you can't check it for `null`. Instead check it whether it's `0` or below for instance.

Comment: Since double is a primitive and not an Object you cannot compare it with null. Compare it with number (zero). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50711708/error-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-double-null-how-to-fix?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090077/how-to-check-if-a-double-is-null

Comment: pls share NPE log ! i guess latitude or longitude is fine

Answer (score 5):

**double** is a primitive type, it cannot be null, instead you can use **Double** and then compare it to null

Answer (score 1):

I guess latitude or longitude is fine and your pickupLatLng or destinationLatLng is null and give you NPE so i think you must use this code instead

```
if (pickupLatLng != null && destinationLatLng != null) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, a Java double cannot be null, and cannot be compared with a Java null. (The double type is a primitive (non-reference) type and primitive types cannot be null.)

Try this,

```
if( pickupLatLng.latitude != 0 && pickupLatLng.longitude != 0 && destinationLatLng.latitude != 0 && destinationLatLng.longitude != 0)
```

Comment: This doesn't add any explanation as to why OP get's this error and so the answer isn't helpful at all. Rephrase your answer or delete it.