# How to compare two double numbers in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have some trouble to write test script where I have to check if discount and prices on the [website](http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=8&controller=category) are correct. I wrote something like that:

```
    @Test
    public void discountOnTheDress() {
        WebElement dressLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#block_top_menu > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a"));
        dressLink.click();

        List<WebElement> listOfDresses = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.product-container"));

        for (WebElement e: listOfDresses) {

            double endPrice = 0;

            if(e.getText().contains("%")) {
                String priceWithDollarBeforeDiscount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"center_column\"]/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]")).getText();
                String priceWithoutDollarBeforeDiscount = priceWithDollarBeforeDiscount.replace("$", "");
                double priceBeforeDiscount = Double.parseDouble(priceWithoutDollarBeforeDiscount);

                String priceWithDollarAfterDiscount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"center_column\"]/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]")).getText();
                String priceWithoutDollarAfterDiscount = priceWithDollarAfterDiscount.replace("$", "");
                double priceAfterDiscount = Double.parseDouble(priceWithoutDollarAfterDiscount);

                String discountWithPercent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"center_column\"]/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]")).getText();
                String discountWithoutPercent = discountWithPercent.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                double discount = Double.parseDouble(discountWithoutPercent);

                endPrice = ((discount / 100) * priceBeforeDiscount) + priceAfterDiscount;
                Assert.assertEquals(priceAfterDiscount, endPrice);
            }
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work and I don't know how to handle that. Does someone have any idea how to write it correctly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two double values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java)

Comment: This question isn't specific to Selenium, it's more about comparing two doubles or two strings really. Since you pull it off the page as a string, you could compare it to a string and at that point it's easy... you can just assert that the two strings are equal.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, I can think of two easy ways -

First - [`==`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

```
if(priceAfterDiscount == endPrice) {
    //Double values are same
}
```

Second - [`java.lang.Double.compare()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_compare.htm)

```
if(Double.compare(priceAfterDiscount, endPrice) == 0) {
    //Double values are same
}
```