# I changed a variable inside a method, how do I access the changed variable?

Tags: java

I declared the private Complex variable 'root' in my class. 
I set the value of root to a Complex number inside the void method 'iterate'

I wish to print the new value of 'root' (line 60) but when I try, it prints as null. So I don't think it is calling the correct 'root'.

My code:

```
class Newton {

public static final int MAXITER = 20;
public static final double TOL = 1.0e-10;


private Polynomial f;        //Polynomial
private Polynomial fp;      //Derivative of the polynomial

private Complex root;
private int numIterations;
private int err;


//Basic constructor. Calculate and set fp in this method.

public Newton(Polynomial p) {
  this.f = p;
  this.fp = p.derivative();
}

// Newton-Rapshon method



public void iterate(Complex z0) {
      Complex[] z = new Complex[MAXITER];
      z[0] = z0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i<MAXITER ; i++){
        if(fp.evaluate(z[i]).abs() <= TOL){
          this.err = -1;
          return;
        }
      z[i+1] = z[i].add((f.evaluate(z[i])).divide(fp.evaluate(z[i])));
        if(f.evaluate(z[i]).abs() != TOL){
          this.err = -2;
          return;
      } if (f.evaluate(z[i]).abs() <= TOL){
          this.err = 0;
          this.root = z[i];
          this.numIterations = i;
          return;
      }
    }}

    // Tester function.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Basic tester: find a root of f(z) = z^3-1 from the starting point
        // z_0 = 1+i.
        Complex[] coeff = new Complex[] { new Complex(-1.0,0.0), new Complex(),
                                          new Complex(), new Complex(1.0,0.0) };
        Polynomial p    = new Polynomial(coeff);
        Newton     n    = new Newton(p);

    Complex z0 = new Complex(1.0,1.0);
        n.iterate(z0);
        System.out.println(n.root);
    }}
```

Comment: That code will not compile, it looks like you're missing a method signature after the constructor. Anyway, did you try debugging?

Comment: You have lots of code outside of any function. How would that even build? Please create a [mcve] to show us, that builds and exhibits your problem.

Comment: Your `for-loop` isn't inside any method. I would assume your code doesn't even compile

Comment: You probably don't reach the line where `this.root` is set because '==' on `double` is higly dangerous. Prefer a method which accepts an error margin.

Comment: The above comments are valid, but the crux of your issue is that root, or rather n.root is private.  It won’t be accessible in ‘static void main’.  You either make it public, or provide a ‘public getter’ that returns the private root value.

Comment: I edited the '==' to '<=' because that makes more sense! and I changed the last line to `System.out.println(n.getRoot());` and it seems to work now

Comment: Check `err` before checking `root`, you are not handling errors at the moment. Only if `err == 0` you should check `root`. Consider using exceptions for error handling.

Comment: I suspect you return form `iterate` at this line : `if(f.evaluate(z[i]).abs() != TOL).` See [How to compare two double values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a getter for `root` in your `Newton` class since it is a private field.

```
class Newton {

public static final int MAXITER = 20;
public static final double TOL = 1.0e-10;


private Polynomial f;        //Polynomial
private Polynomial fp;      //Derivative of the polynomial

private Complex root;
private int numIterations;
private int err;


//Basic constructor. Calculate and set fp in this method.

public Newton(Polynomial p) {
  this.f = p;
  this.fp = p.derivative();
}
public Complex getRoot(){
  return this.root;
}
}
```

You can then use the getter instead of trying to access `n.root` (i.e., using `newtonObj.getRoot()` instead of `newtonObj.root`):

```
// Tester function.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Basic tester: find a root of f(z) = z^3-1 from the starting point
    // z_0 = 1+i.
    Complex[] coeff = new Complex[] { new Complex(-1.0,0.0), new Complex(),
                                      new Complex(), new Complex(1.0,0.0) };
    Polynomial p    = new Polynomial(coeff);
    Newton     n    = new Newton(p);

Complex z0 = new Complex(1.0,1.0);
    n.iterate(z0);
    System.out.println(n.getRoot());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the getter and it works now!! thanks :)

Comment: @dwaras No problem.