# Why wont Min and Max num update

Tags: java

Very new to Java (please don't laugh)and trying to do a project that asks user for a number and will keep track of the highest and lowest number when the user enter a sentinel value. My error is the I cannot get max and min values to update when going through the while loop.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a double number, or 'q' to quit");
    double currentNum = 0.0;
    double maxNum=0.0;
    double minNum=0.0;
    int count = 0;
    
    
    while(sc.hasNextDouble())
    {
    currentNum = sc.nextDouble();
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
    if(count ==1)
    {
        minNum = currentNum;
        maxNum = currentNum;
        System.out.println("Please enter a double number, or 'q' to quit");
    }
    else if(count!=1){
    if (currentNum > maxNum)
    {
        currentNum = maxNum;
        System.out.println("You are in currentNum > maxNum");
        System.out.println(maxNum);
        System.out.println("Please enter a double number, or 'q' to quit");
        
        
        
        System.out.println(maxNum);
        
    }
    else if (currentNum < minNum)
    {
        currentNum = minNum;
        System.out.println("You are in currentNum < minum");
        System.out.println("Please enter a double number, or 'q' to quit");
        
        
        
    }
    
    }
    }
   System.out.println("Min num " + minNum);
   System.out.println("Max num " + maxNum);
    
}
}
```

Comment: You are updating the value of currentNum instead of maxNum/minNum.

Comment: Any specific reason you're comparing double values? It's generally not a good idea to compare floating point values

Answer (score 0):

I think you got your logic mixed up.

When you get a number larger or smaller than `maxNum` you want to update `maxNum` to `currentNum` not the other way around.

Also the `count == 1` if condition is redundant.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a double number, or 'q' to quit");
        double currentNum = 0.0;
        double maxNum=(double)Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double minNum=(double)Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int count = 0;
        
        
        while(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            currentNum = sc.nextDouble();
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
            if (currentNum > maxNum){
                maxNum = currentNum;
                System.out.println("You are in currentNum > maxNum");
                System.out.println("Maximum : "+maxNum);
            }
            else if (currentNum < minNum){
                minNum = currentNum;
                System.out.println("You are in currentNum < minum");
                System.out.println("Minimum : "+minNum);
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter a double number, or 'q' to quit");
        }
       System.out.println("Min num " + minNum);
       System.out.println("Max num " + maxNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed is that you're comparing `double` variables. Generally it's not a good idea comparing floating point values because they have precision problems. You should use `long` or `int` instead. If you really don't have any other choice and have to use `double`, you should checkout this question: [How to compare two double values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java)

As pointed out in comment, you're updating `currentNum` instead of `maxNum`/`minNum`. So your else-if block for updating min-max value should look like this:

```java
    if (currentNum > maxNum) {
        System.out.printf("You are in currentNum(%d) > maxNum(%d)", currentNum, maxNum);
        //currentNum = maxNum; // <- Wrong, doesn't update maxNum; currentNum would be updated in next loop iteration anyway
        maxNum = currentNum; // <- What you should be doing
    }
    else if (currentNum < minNum) {
        System.out.printf("You are in currentNum(%d) < minNum(%d)", currentNum, minNum);
        //currentNum = minNum; // <- Wrong, doesn't update minNum
        minNum = currentNum;   // <- What you should be doing
    }
```