# Java precision during division and multiplication alterneting process

Tags: java, double, precision, division, multiplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resolve a Java Rounding Double issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue)

Please Help, 
I programm some calculator in Java. I use double type. Double has 15 digits after the decimal point. I have problem with the following:

1/3 * 3 = 0.9999999999999999

I need 1/3 * 3 = 1

How can I solve this problem?
I keep result in Double. The same problem I have with other mathematical operations, for example

sqrt(6) = 2.449489742783, and next I square the result and I get: 5.999999999999999

Answer (score 3):

You're dealing with inherent limitations of floating-point arithmetic.

- Read the paper [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).
- For equality-checking, you should be using something like `abs(x-y) < epsilon` rather than `x == y`
- For display purposes, you should round to the nearest decimal place that you actually care about.

Answer (score 0):

Certain numbers cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point.  1/3 is one of them.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point  For that matter, 1/3 cannot be represented exactly in decimal either.

Your calculator should use a `java.text.NumberFormat` to present the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing this is due to the computers inability to understand infinity.

A computer has limitations, so it does not understand the fact that 1/3 is never-ending. This causes it to round. This can be solved as Jason S posted above. Using these special class, people have started to program ways to computer whether or not something goes to infinity, then attempt to deal with it.