# Bitwise Not for double in Java

Tags: java, bit

In Java, the bitwise not operator (`~`) inverts all bits of an integer or long. But why is this not possible for a `double`? Is there any method of using this operation on a `double`? I am writing my own programming language in Java (this is NOT a homework assignment), and I believe that bitwise should be included for doubles.

Any ways of using bitwise not on doubles?

**EDIT**: This is not a duplicate of [How to perform a bitwise operation on floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723575/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operation-on-floating-point-numbers), because I am using Java as opposed to the discussed C. I also know that there is no possible way using the syntax of the language, but the answers there seem to cast the `double` to an `int`. I need to keep the double as it is, without changing it to an `int` or `long`.

**EDIT**: The bitwise not isn't what I thought it would be. It seems to perform `*-1 - 1` on the input. Therefore, my question now becomes:

I wish to turn a double into binary (see my other question ), invert all of the bits (0 to 1 and 1 to 0), then convert it back to a double.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you expect the negation of `0` to be... in binary as a `double`.

Comment: What meaning do bitwise operations have for floating-point values?

Comment: Well, you could use `Double.doubleToRawLongBits`, negate it, and then `Double.longToDoubleBits`. Doesn't mean much though.

Comment: But the result won't *mean* anything. It'll be 'the bitwise inverse of a floating point number', which has no intrinsic or mathematical value.

Comment: The inverse of `0` should be `1`. `0` is `0b0`, and the inverse of that is `0b1`. Also, using long bits results in `NaN` most of the time.

Comment: For (signed) integers, adding Not-itself will always result in `-1`. Doing the same with a double will probably only result in garbage.

Comment: @JamesSmith ... so if you think the inverse of 0 should be 1, and the inverse of 1 should be 0, what is the inverse of 3? or 7? or for that matter 2.718 ?

Comment: @khelwood I have just found out that the bitwise not isn't quite what I expected. It looks like `~x = (-1 * x) - 1`.

Comment: Just for the principle, I quite agree this is *not* a duplicate of the other suggested question, although it is more or less the same problem indeed.

Comment: I have decided that I will not include bitwise operators on doubles, for the reason of recursive decimals losing precision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java didn't supply the `~` operator on the floating-point types `float` and `double` because such an operation isn't meaningful.

You can simulate it with this method:

```
public static double performNotOnDouble(double d)
{
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(~Double.doubleToLongBits(d));
}
```

But the results don't have any real meaning:

```
0.0: NaN
1.0: -3.9999999999999996
10.0: -0.43749999999999994
-1.0: 3.9999999999999996
0.01: -440.31999999999994
3.141592653589793: -1.4292036732051032
2.718281828459045: -1.6408590857704772
Infinity: -2.225073858507201E-308
-Infinity: 2.225073858507201E-308
NaN: -1.1125369292536E-308
```

There is no point to taking the bit-complement of a floating-point type, because the result doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: It probably means something, but it's not obvious what it is

Comment: @Smac89 what the answer means is that the result has no *useful* meaning.

Comment: Here is a *practical* reason inverting the bits cannot lead to a meaningful number: in IEEE 754 double precision, "the most significant bit is always 1 for a normalized number, this bit is not typically stored and is called the 'hidden bit'." ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand)) – and you cannot invert what is not there.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Double and convert it using [doubleToRawLongBits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double)) and then use any bitwise operator you want.

However, I don't know what this will suppose to mean :$ but it will definitely work... Is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You'd really need to read up about [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) before considering this sort of operation, and [this part of the JLS spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).

> The inverse of 0 should be 1. 0 is 0b0, and the inverse of that is 0b1. Also, using long bits results in NaN most of the time.

While `0.0d` is indeed `0b0`, `0b1` is certainly not the bitwise inverse of `0.0d`.

- `Double.doubleToLongBits(0.0d))` = `0`
- `Double.doubleToLongBits(1.0d)` = `4607182418800017408`
- `Double.longBitsToDouble(0b1)` = `4.9E-324`

In general, each double value really represents a range of values around that value you're able to print out, taking into account some imprecision.

You should also check ["How to resolve a Java Rounding Double issue"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179427/372643) (and possibly a number of questions that link to it).

Bitwise operations in that context are generally meaningless.

(Along these lines, you can read a bit about `strictfp` for your general Java knowledge.)