# Math.round() not working

Tags: java, math

I'm working on a calculator in Java but the "." buttons function won't work. if I remove the `Math.round()` I sometimes get 1.1999999 instead of 1.2. How do I solve this problem? I've tried looking up several `Math.round()` solutions on stack overflow but none of them worked.

```java
x = Math.round(x + (y / (Math.pow(10, z)) * 1000) / (double) 1000);
```

the code above is what I've tried so far.

Comment: At rounding issues you can also take a look into this question: [How to resolve a Java Rounding Double issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue)

Comment: How are you displaying your double? eg. 1.2 might be represented as something closer to 1.1999999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to round the solution before dividing.

```
double d = x + y / Math.pow(10, z);
double r = Math.round(d * 1e3) / 1e3; // round to 3 decimal places
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try format your text using NumberFormat class

```
public String formatNumber(int n){
    NumberFormat f= NumberFormat.getInstance();
    f.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);// minimum digits after comma
    f.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);//maximum digits after comma
    String formattedN = f.format(n);
    return formattedN;
}
```