# Backpropagation: networkerror of one testinput rises, the others go down, whats wrong?

Tags: java, networking, backpropagation

I am currently trying to program a neural network... for learning I want to use the backpropagation algorithm! My problem is, that I don't know where my error is.
I try to train it the logical AND.

My network errors after the first round are:

- 28.68880035284087 for INPUT 1|1
- 22.17048518538824 for INPUT 1|0
- 21.346787829014342 for INPUT 0|1
- 20.44791655274438 for INPUT 0|0

If I make a few iterations my errors are like this:

- 34.17584528001372 for INPUT 1|1
- 18.315643070675343 for INPUT 1|0
- 17.568891920535222 for INPUT 0|1
- 17.753497551261436 for INPUT 0|0

I have absolutely no idea why the error for INPUT 1|1 is growing, while the others get smaller...

Here's my code:

classes for the testdata:

```
public class Trainingset
{
private double[] input;
private double[] target;

public Trainingset(double[] input, double[] target)
{
    this.input = input;
    this.target = target;
}

public double[] getInput()
{
    return input;
}

public double[] getTarget()
{
    return target;
}
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class TrainingData
{
private List<Trainingset> trainingSets;
private Random random;
private int nextEntry;

public TrainingData()
{
    random = new Random();
    trainingSets = new ArrayList<Trainingset>();
    nextEntry = 0;
}

public void addData(double[] input, double[] target)
{
    Trainingset ts = new Trainingset(input.clone(), target.clone());
    trainingSets.add(ts);
}

public Trainingset getRandomTrainingset()
{
    return trainingSets.get(random.nextInt(trainingSets.size()));
}

public Trainingset getNext()
{
    if(nextEntry == trainingSets.size())
        nextEntry = 0;
    return trainingSets.get(nextEntry++);
}
}
```

the networkclass:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FFN3
{
private List<FFNlayer3> layers;
private double learningrate = 0.45;
private double momentum = 0.9;
private double outputError;
private double networkErrkor;

public FFN3()
{
    layers = new ArrayList<>();
    layers.add(new FFNlayer3(2));
    layers.add(new FFNlayer3(1));
    layers.get(0).setNextLayer(layers.get(1));
    layers.get(1).setPrevLayer(layers.get(0));

    double[][] ItoH = {
            { 0.4, 0.1 },
            { -0.1, -0.1 }
    };

    double[][] HtoO = {
            { 0.06, -0.4 }
    };      

    layers.get(0).setWeights(ItoH);
    layers.get(1).setWeights(HtoO);
    networkErrkor = Double.MAX_VALUE;
}

public void learn(TrainingData td)
{
    Trainingset ts = td.getNext();
    double[] results = compute(ts.getInput());
    double error = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
        error += Math.pow(ts.getTarget()[i] - results[i], 2);
    }
    networkErrkor = error / results.length;
    layers.get(layers.size()-1).updateWeights(learningrate, momentum, ts.getTarget());
    layers.get(0).updateHiddenWeights(learningrate, momentum, ts.getInput());
}

public double getNetworkError()
{
    return networkErrkor;
}

public double[] compute(double[] input)
{
    return layers.get(0).compute(input);
}
}
```

The layerclass:

```
public class FFNlayer3
{
private double[][] incomingWeights;
private double[][] prevWeightChanges;
private double[] neuronValues;
private double[] neuronSums;
private double[] errors;
private FFNlayer3 prevLayer;
private FFNlayer3 nextLayer;

public FFNlayer3(int neuroncount)
{
    neuronValues = new double[neuroncount];
    neuronSums = new double[neuroncount];
    errors = new double[neuroncount];
    nextLayer = null;
    prevLayer = null;
}

public void setWeights(double[][] weights)
{
    incomingWeights = weights;
    prevWeightChanges = new double[incomingWeights.length][incomingWeights[0].length];
}

public void setPrevLayer(FFNlayer3 prevLayer)
{
    this.prevLayer = prevLayer;
}

public void setNextLayer(FFNlayer3 nextLayer)
{
    this.nextLayer = nextLayer;
}

public void updateWeights(double learningrate, double momentum, double[] targetValues)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < errors.length; i++)
    {
        errors[i] = neuronValues[i] * (1 - neuronValues[i]) * (targetValues[i] - neuronValues[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < incomingWeights.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < incomingWeights[i].length; j++)
        {
            double delta = learningrate * errors[i] * prevLayer.getNeuronValues()[j];
            incomingWeights[i][j] += delta + momentum * prevWeightChanges[i][j];
        }
    }
    prevLayer.updateHiddenWeights(learningrate, momentum);
}

public void updateHiddenWeights(double learningrate, double momentum)
{
    if(prevLayer==null)
        return;

    for(int i = 0; i < errors.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < nextLayer.getErrors().length; j++)
        {
            errors[i] += nextLayer.getErrors()[j] * nextLayer.getWeights()[j][i];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < incomingWeights.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < incomingWeights[i].length; j++)
        {
            double delta = learningrate * errors[i] * prevLayer.getNeuronValues()[j];
            incomingWeights[i][j] += delta + momentum * prevWeightChanges[i][j];
        }
    }       
    prevLayer.updateHiddenWeights(learningrate, momentum);
}   

public void updateHiddenWeights(double learningrate, double momentum, double[] input)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < errors.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < nextLayer.getErrors().length; j++)
        {
            errors[i] += nextLayer.getErrors()[j] * nextLayer.getWeights()[j][i];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < incomingWeights.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < incomingWeights[i].length; j++)
        {
            double delta = learningrate * errors[i] * input[j];
            incomingWeights[i][j] += delta + momentum * prevWeightChanges[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public double[][] getWeights()
{
    return incomingWeights;
}

public double[] getErrors()
{
    return errors;
}

public double[] getNeuronValues()
{
    return neuronValues;
}

public double[] compute(double[] input)
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < neuronValues.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < incomingWeights[i].length; j++)
        {
            neuronSums[i] += input[j] * incomingWeights[i][j];
        }
        neuronValues[i] = SIGMOID(neuronSums[i]);
        neuronSums = new double[neuronSums.length];
    }
    if(nextLayer==null)
        return neuronValues;
    return nextLayer.compute(neuronValues);
}

private double SIGMOID(double value)
{
    return 1 / (1+ Math.exp(-value));
}
}
```

And the snippet from my main:

```
    FFN3 network = new FFN3();
    double[] input = new double[2];
    double[] target = new double[1];
    TrainingData td = new TrainingData();

    input[0] = 1;
    input[1] = 1;
    target[0] = 1;
    td.addData(input, target);

    input[0] = 1;
    input[1] = 0;
    target[0] = 0;
    //target[1] = 1;
    td.addData(input, target);

    input[0] = 0;
    input[1] = 1;
    target[0] = 0;
    td.addData(input, target);  

    input[0] = 0;
    input[1] = 0;
    target[0] = 0;
    td.addData(input, target);

    while(Double.compare(network.getNetworkError(), 0.001)>0)
    {
        network.learn(td);
        System.out.println(network.getNetworkError()*100);
    }
```

I was using this document: http://www.dataminingmasters.com/uploads/studentProjects/NeuralNetworks.pdf

The values after the first epoch are similar to the values in the document... what is wrong? Is it the document, my code or both?

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

you may try with **BigDecimal** instead of double, as they could cause trouble (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue) for further information )

Comment: Welcome to SO. This better be a comment instead of an answer. Please try to earn enogh reputation for that.