# Double multiplying with int issue

Tags: java, android

```
double temp = 64.1;
System.out.println("Result = " + (temp*1000));
```

The result would be:

```
Result = 64099.99999999999
```

But the actual result should be `64100`

In case of Double data type

```
double a = ((temp * 1000) % (0.5 * 1000));
a=7.275957614183426E-12;
```

In case of casting it to float

```
((((float) temp) * 1000) % (0.5 * 1000));
a=0.0;
```

Why this behaviour?

Comment: So you the the answer to be 64100

Comment: Voting this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve a Java Rounding Double issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue)

Comment: It's not an issue, that's totally expected when you operate with float or double. What's the problem?

Comment: Ie expected output! If you need other one as output use Math.round()

Answer (score 4):

Is a typical **numeric problem with floating point numbers**, when you multiple e.g. double * int.

First option use Math.round:

```
Math.round((temp*1000))
```

Second option use BigDecimal class:

```
 BigDecimal temp = BigDecimal.valueOf(64.1);
 BigDecimal thousand = BigDecimal.valueOf(1000);
 BigDecimal result = temp.multiply(thousand);

 //example how to extract int or double value 
 int intResult = result.intValue();
 double doubleResult = result.doubleValue();
 System.out.println("Result = " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ceil() method of JAVA.

double temp = 64.1;

System.out.println("Result = " + Math.ceil(temp*1000));

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The double in Java represents floating point number. It has 64 bits value, which consist of:

- Sign bit: 1 bit
- Exponent: 11 bits
- Significant precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Unlike fixed point numbers (byte, int, long), floating point number can't always consistently return exact same representation of a number. That's the reason why you get the result 64099.99999999999 instead of 64100.

Use BigDecimal in Java in order to get better control of decimal places.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
double temp = 64.1;
int x = 1000;
System.out.println("Answer :" + Math.round((temp*x)));
```