# Double.parseDouble(String value) produces inconsistent value

Tags: java, double, precision

I'm trying to convert my following String to double value

```
String str = "26315000000253009";
System.out.println("Parsing double value i got : "+Double.parseDouble(str));
```

**Result**

```
Parsing double value i got : 2.6315000000253008E16
```

But the expected one is `2.6315000000253009E16`

Why does this inconsistency prevails?

Comment: This question must have been asked before, but more importantly why does this matter?

Comment: see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : problem comes from json. When I add the string value `26315000000253009` and obtain it as json.getLong() - json does the following conversion `Double.parseDouble("26315000000253009")` - when it is not a number. So, I'm getting inconsistent result there. But I'm curious to know how Double.parseDouble() gives inconsistent result..

Comment: Try
System.out.printf("Parsing double: %f\n", Double.parseDouble(str)); But be aware that it will give you 26315000000253008.00000.

Comment: Double cannot exactly represent all numbers. For `26315000000253009` the nearest representable numbers are `26315000000253008` and `26315000000253012`.

Comment: @ThomasKläger : What's the reason behind such limitation.. Just curious to know what happens internally during `String` to `Double` conversion.. And how much length does `Double` can hold the value - so that it can produce accurate result?

Comment: @sAm : It produces some other value like `2.6315000000253004E16`

Comment: @rajasubasubramanian33 You have to keep in mind that these numbers are stored in binary and the binary representation can not always accurately represent the number you desire.

Comment: @ThomasKläger : How could you say that the nearest possible numbers are `26315000000253008` and `26315000000253012`?

Comment: Doubles only have about 15.9 decimal digits of integral precision. Your number has 17. Your expectations are baseless.

Comment: The reason behind the limitation is that double use 64 bits to store very small (around 10^-324) and very large (around 10^308) numbers. Therefore it cannot use all 64 bits to store the digits of the number. For details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers. I found the nearest numbers by doing `double n = Double.parseDouble("26315000000253009"); System.out.println(n); System.out.println(n+1); System.out.println(n+2); System.out.println(n+4);`

Comment: @EJP : Does 15 represents `manitssa` part and `9` represents `exponential` part?

Comment: @rajasubasubramanian33 No, 15.9 is the approximate number of decimal digits that would have the same number of values as 53 binary digits.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan : I couldn't get you what does `15.9` mean? Please explain me bit more..

Comment: @ThomasKläger You can also use [Math.nextUp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-double-).

Comment: @rajasubasubramanian33 In practice, in this situation,  it means "slightly less than 16". It is calculated as 53*log_10(2).

Comment: Okay @PatriciaShanahan. Does 16 represents the number of decimal digits?

Comment: @rajasubasubramanian33 No, ***15.9*** represents the number of decimal digits, as I originally wrote.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan thanks, I didn't know this method. I suspected that something similar should exist but did not take the time to search for it.

Comment: @EJP : how could you say that the number of decimal digits which it could represent is **15.9** - Just curious to know..

Comment: @rajasubasubramanian33 One way of looking at it is that the smallest natural number that cannot be represented exactly is 9,007,199,254,740,993. All the natural numbers that take 1 through 15 digits, and most of the 16 digit ones can be represented exactly.

Comment: @rajasubasubramanian33 The essential point here is that whether you think of it as 15.9 or 16, it is still less than 17.

Comment: Yeah !! @EJP :)